# Facebook Feed dialog not showing any picture

Tags: facebook, feed

Why facebook feed is not showing the picture?
I tried many different images and it seems that it's always trying to crawl from the page and is ignoring all the params...

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=751057878399077&display=popup&link=https%3A%2F%2Fwithpresence.co%2Fin%2Fsocial-crafts-wine-%2B-craft&picture=https%3A%2F%2Ftheglint.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com%2Fsocial-crafts-banner.jpg&name=Social%20Crafts%3A%20Wine%20%2B%20Craft&description=MyDescription

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_9

> The following fields are deprecated for edges and dialogs that allow
>   attaching links to posts:
>
> - picture
> - name
> - caption
> - thumbnail
> - description

Comment: My share button was created dinamicaly. So I need remove completly FB share :(